# How to execute a curl command in Python and get the response and pass it through other code

Tags: python-3.x, curl, libcurl, pycurl, shlex

I have a curl command.  I want to execute in in Python and fetch the response to pass it through other code.

```
curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=refresh_token' -d 'refresh_token=Ew38UXVKS3kc0axFt6MdDklUnoHpipxTzDWBmKlXAG9ImvGafbbaUhQndv89e677' -d 'client_id=3qkm5h4wh765b3khiws0z8hdpkc56jhs' -d 'client_secret=h9AeXzZL3KATJuaHmimFFBRBDZQrp9tr' -X POST
```

How can I execute the script in Python and get the response and pass it through other code?

When I am executing the curl script in CMD, I am getting this response:

```
{"access_token":"uz843jpIiEWnu0CcuT9as2XbA3UEQTR67","expires_in":4261,"restricted_to":[],"refresh_token":"GsDaP6VyUpHN8vDHbz9ktAjLfMLN0dFL6PMIK4fmDH8eKRqR360vDhQTBhIMZxy67","token_type":"bearer"}
```

From the above response I need to take the `access_token` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like avloss said - try out `requests`.

Another great resource is the application [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

It will let you try out any http calls you'd like, and then can also translate that into/out of curl and/or python requests code for you (and a bunch of other languages).

I find it really useful when trying to figure how to use `requests` for anything more than simple http calls.

Comment: Hi Richard, I am not getting the response after i executed the command as above.

Comment: which code?  avloss' python?

what I'd suggest is first try getting you query working in Postman.  Then after it's working there use Postman to generate the equivalent python requests call.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `requests` library (`pip install requests`)

```py
import requests
url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token'
data = {
    'grant_type':'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token':'***',
    'client_id':'***',
    'client_secret':'***'
}
response = requests.post(url, data).json()
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for the updates. But I am seeing below error while trying to execute the script.<Response [200]>

Comment: "Response 200" usually means success, I'm not sure how you're getting that error.

Comment: I am assuming it as an error as i am unable to see the response.can you please let me know how can i see the response as below.{"access_token":"uz843jpIiEWnu0CcuT9as2XbA3UEQTR67","expires_in":4261,"restricted_to":[],"refresh_token":"GsDaP6VyUpHN8vDHbz9ktAjLfMLN0dFL6PMIK4fmDH8eKRqR360vDhQTBhIMZxy67","token_type":"bearer"}